# Installing packages

Tags: android

When I try to install the packages, all I get is :`File not found: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\temp\android-16_r02.zip` (Access is denied)

At the end `Nothing was installed` gets flashed.The latest version of `JDK` in also installed in my computer.

What should I do?

Comment: Check your file permission? ls -la

Comment: Looks like a permission issue. Either install as administrator or change the location to a place where your user account has permission.

Comment: I had a similar kind of problem but mine was due to Package installer down.I think ur firewall is restricting it Or due to administration permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

Run as Administrator, it may work... i had faced similar kind of issue. Make your system to run as administrator for installing file.. Its permission problem thats why you are getting Access Denied